# If statement with command line parameters in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

There has to be something I'm missing here.

I'm writing a batch script and within the script I have multiple statements like this one:

```sh
::Display Help Message.
if /I "%~1" =="help" goto help
:help
echo [help msg]
goto :exit

::Check if script is set to clean mode.
if /I "%~1" =="clean" goto :cleanup
::Check if script is set to silent mode.
if /I "%~3" =="silent" goto :silent
```

However, if I run the script with a parameter, be it 'help' or not, I get this error:

[image: Error Screenshot]

The same thing happens with no parameters.

Does anyone know the fix to this?

Comment: What you have posted is exactly the same as having a one line script containing `echo [Help Text]`. Did you read and understand any of the comments @Mofi, has provided? A batch file runs each line after the previous unless you tell it not to, so it goes to `:help` regardless of whether you tell it to or not, the same is true for `goto :exit`, which you should not use anyhow. You should use `GoTo :EOF` which is a special instruction, _(which does not require a `:EOF` label)_, meaning go to the end of the file.

Comment: see my updated code. I've added a few of the parameters I've got in my script. Can you see what I mean now?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example script idea which should display the help message, whenever no argument is passed to it, or the first argument passed is either `?`, `/?`, `-?`, `--?`, `h`, `/h`, `-h`, `--h`, `help`, `/help`, `-help`, or `--help`.

```sh
@Echo "%~1" | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R /C:"\"\"" /C:"\"?\""^
 /C:"\"/?\"" /C:"\"\-?\"" /C:"\"\-\-?\"" /C:"\"h\"" /C:"\"/h\"" /C:"\"\-h\""^
 /C:"\"\-\-h\"" /C:"\"help\"" /C:"\"/help\"" /C:"\"\-help\"" /C:"\"\-\-help\""^
 1>NUL && GoTo ShowHelp

@Rem Your code goes below here

@Echo Off
Echo [main code]
Pause

@Rem Your code ends above here
@GoTo :EOF

:ShowHelp
Echo [help msg]
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 5 /NoBreak 1>NUL
```

*Obviously the three lines of code `@Echo Off`, and `Echo [main code]`, and `Pause`, are there only as examples.*